# Putting the results of a jquery.form ajax call into a <canvas> or <img> tag

Tags: canvas, jqueryform

I have a script that takes a large CSV file via multipart POST and returns a png. I want to [submit the form via ajax](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#api) and display that png on the current webpage. I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18976327/binary-array-to-canvas) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4409445/base64-png-data-to-html5-canvas), I pieced together a [nonworking jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zippy1981/r38m2/4/). I've tried with and without transforming the returned string to a `Uint8Array`. I don't know how to get more useful information from the `Image.onerror` event.

My function looks as follows:

```
$('#btnDoIt').click(function() {
    $("#theForm").ajaxSubmit(function(data) {
        var imageData = new Uint8Array(data.length);
        for(var i=0, j=data.length; i<j; ++i){
            imageData[i]=data.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([imageData], {type: "image/jpeg"});
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var img = new Image();
        var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");
        img.onload = function() {
            /// draw image to canvas
            context.drawImage(url, 1,1);
        }
        img.onerror = function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        };
        img.src = url;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [XMLHttpRequest.responseType](http://www.javascripture.com/XMLHttpRequest#responseType) property to get a blob back from the AJAX request instead of trying to parse the string manually. I wasn't able to figure out how to set the property with the ajaxSubmit method you were using, but it's not hard to do manually with an [XMLHttpRequest](http://www.javascripture.com/XMLHttpRequest) and [FormData](http://www.javascripture.com/FormData).  Here's an updated function that does the conversion:

```
$('#btnDoIt').click(function() {
    var form = document.getElementById('theForm');

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open('GET', form.action, /* async = */ true);

    request.responseType = 'blob'; // Get a Blob back in the response property 

    request.onload = function() {
        var blob = request.response;
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

        var img = new Image();
        var context = document.getElementById('myCanvas').getContext("2d");

        img.onload = function() {
            /// draw image to canvas
            context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
        };
        img.onerror = function(error) {
            console.error(error);
        };
        img.src = url;
    };
    request.send(new FormData(form));
});
```